# What is the difference of `__new__` and `__init__` methods in metaclasses?

Tags: python-3.x, metaclass

```
class MyMeta(type):
    def __init__(self, name, bases, attrs):
        pass
        
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        attrs['desc'] = lambda self: "the test"
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
```

```
class MyMeta(type):
    def __init__(self, name, bases, attrs):
        self.desc = lambda self: "the test"

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
```

```
b = Bar()
print(b.desc())
```

What is the difference between adding desc to `__new__` and adding it to `__init__`? The results are the same

Comment: the big difference is in the order you call each of the __new__ or __init__ methods. The new method will be called first (constructor), passing "self" to init (initializer). For the rest, both are possible implementations, depending on the purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only with metaclasses, but for all classes in general, everything that can be done in `__init__` could also be done in  `__new__`. In this order - the converse does not apply.

So, for classes in general, metaclasses included - `__new__` is called the "constructor" of the class: with the most meaningful thing for Python code being that at the entry-point of `__new__` the instance to be created does not exist yet: one get access to the "raw" data that will be used to build the instance.

As a matter of fact, without resorting to a native-code extension (almost always the built-in code in the Python runtime), it is not even possible to *create* any object in Python. Be it a "normal" instance, or a class (the instance of a metaclass) - as the memory allocation, low-level memory structures, and such are all defined at the cAPI level in the cPython runtime.

So, unless one will "fake" the creation of an object (returning an already existing object, or triggering an external action and returning None), at some point the `__new__` method have to call the method on its superclass until `object.__new__` or other `__new__` method defined in the C runtime (like `type.__new__` for metaclasses) is reached.

That super call will return the created instance: the same object that is passed as the first (`self`) argument to `__init__` and other regular methods.

Implementers who write a `__new__` method have therefore the option to interact with the data to build the object prior to this `super()` call - in the case in your example, you are injecting the `desc` attribute in the dictionary that is used to build the class namespace - or *after* this call: in which case one can interate with the newly minted instance as any regular interaction of an object: you could add your `desc` as an attribute in `__new__` like this:

```
...
class MyMeta(type):

    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, attrs):
        cls = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        cls.desc = lambda self: "the test"
        return cls
```

However, if one does not need to change the data before creating the instance itself, there is no need to ever writting a `__new__` method: if you can do what you need in the `__init__` you are good: just do that.

(Also, in general, one will only need to write one of the two methods: no need to write the other one as a no-operation, if it will not be used).

Just one additional note for metaclasses: the newly created class' `__init_subclass__` and any `__set_name__` methods in one of its attributes will be called before `type.__new__` return - so theses methods run before `__init__` in the metaclass is called.
(There is no way to fine-grain this: Python will always create the class and call those inside `type.__new__` and one can't interact with the new class before they are called).

That all said: keep in mind that metaclasses are in general considered an advanced topic and new features in the language are often designed so one does not need using them. A lot of cases that previously would require metaclasses can nowadays be implemented by having a  `__init_subclass__`  method on a base class.

Comment: Extremely underrated answer! Thank you!